# Need advice on USA b1 b2 visa

Tags: usa, uk, visa-refusals, poland, visa-rejections

Previously my UK and Poland visas got refused. The exhibition is coming up in the USA I want to apply for a visa with my dad. Will my USA visa get rejected?[image: UK page 1]
[image: UK page 2]
[image: poland]

Comment: If your personal / financial circumstances have not significantly improved since your UK and Schengen refusals, you’re likely to be refused by the US as well.

Answer (score 6):

No-one can say for certain of course, but both refusals are rooted in the fact that you were not able to convince the consular officers in your intention to leave after the visit. The US visa officer would want to be convinced of that as well, and they're usually very strict. The brits are also saying, in essence, that you lied. Don't do that. Also, the fact that you have multiple refusals in the past may play against you, if it comes up in some way.

Comment: And if asked you have to tell the truth, the UK and USA share information about things like this.